# How can I find regression model analyses from 2 dataset?

Tags: r, error-handling, regression, linear-regression, predict

```
setwd("C:/Users/sevvalayse.yurtekin/Desktop/hw3")
data = read.table('DSE501_fall2020_HW3.csv', header= T, sep=',')
attach
data
getOption("max.print")

rs<-rowSums(data[,2:76], na.rm = TRUE)
data<-cbind(data,rs)
data

p1<-ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(y = rs, x=year), data=data)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2004,2019,2))
p1

model = lm(rs ~ year )
model
summary(model)
residuals(model)
predict(model)
#model.fit = lm(year~rs)
#summary(model.fit)

new.year<-data.frame(
  year = c(2021,2022,2023)
)
predict(model, newdata = new.year, interval = 'confidence')

data2 = read.table('TUIK_nufus_2019.csv', header = T, sep=",")
data2


total = data2$Total
mydata<-data[-c(1,2,3),]


model2 = lm(mydata~total)
model2
```

Hello, I have an error about the Error in model.frame.default(formula = mydata ~ total, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : invalid type (list) for variable 'mydata'.

How can I fixed? I want to regression analyses from 2 data.

Answer (score 0):

The line that's causing the issue is `model2 = lm(mydata~total)`. `mydata` is not a vector, which is what your dependent variable should be in the `lm` function. When you set `mydata` you do not provide a column name: `mydata<-data[-c(1,2,3), <enter column name of dependent variable>]`

Otherwise you can fit your model with the following syntax (provided your dependent and independent variables are in the same dataframe). Here I just used `y` as a fake variable name: `lm(y ~ total, data = mydata)`